# Drupal 8 - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm new in Drupal 8.

Now, I'm using 8.2.6 version. I am following the tutorial from the [link](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/my-first-drupal-8-module).

I was did it exactly same way.

But The tab menu didn't showed up, how do I access that module?
And when I cleared all cache, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Drupal\bd_contact\AdminController in D:\Dropbox\projects\drupal-8.2.6\modules\custom\bd_contact\src\Controller\AdminController.php on line 7
```

Anyone know why I'm having this error?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP error **Cannot redeclare class** is caused when you try to create a class that you've already created.

For instance:

```
//create one time
class AdminController {}

//and recreated the class with the same name
class AdminController {}
```

You need to validate the `AdminController.php` file if it has two classes with the same name and then compares it with the source code of this tutorial on your GitHub project [link](https://github.com/ThVanC/bd_contact_tutorial/blob/master/src/Controller/AdminController.php) project.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to a GitHub Project!

Comment: @Akki, I don't know if you're thanking or complaining, but the OP is following the example that is available on the GitHub project that I mentioned on the answer. And he said that he following the example at same way, so I just said to him verify the source code.

Comment: If you read question carefully, Question asker has mentioned link and that is not of GitHub. There is actually difference between the code of link and Github. Github code is working fine. You misunderstood.

Comment: I read and edited the question and I followed the same tutorial when I started with Drupal 8, If you try to open the link and read: you will see that there is the code steps and the same code that is available on the Github link that I mentioned on the question.

I don't know how you normally follow the the tutorials, but when anything is not working properly, to take a look the code that you are following is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the name of the controller is not well choosed because there is already a controller named like this in the Drupal core. 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!src!Controller!AdminController.php/class/AdminController/8.2.x

With namespace, it should not cause an issue but try to rename your controller in the class file and in the routing file.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unlikely that anyone would redeclare the same class, especially on the same controller file which is namely, just one class, I assume this problem is due to the lack of a namespace like the colleague above mentions.

Just add a line like below to the top of your class:

`namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Controller;`

I know the question is old but I got here recently and didn't find the exact answer that solved my problem so hope this helps someone.